# How to access "text:" property in the html document or console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following `array` and want to access the `value` under the `text` property:

```
[
  {"detectedLanguage":
    {"language": "hin", "score": 1.0},
      "translations":[
        {"text":"I am a boy", "to":"en"}
      ]
    }
 ]
```

How can i achieve this in `console.log` or `html`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a javscript object to get value of text (you can do this ):

```js
let array = [
   {
      "detectedLanguage":{
         "language":"hin",
         "score":1.0
      },
      "translations":[
         {
            "text":"I am a boy",
            "to":"en"
         }
      ]
   }
]

console.log(array[0].translations[0].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is the following:

```
Array[
  Object{"detectedLanguage":
    Object{"language": "hin", "score": 1.0},
      "translations":Array[
        Object{"text":"I am a boy", "to":"en"}
      ]
    }
 ]
```

To access an array you use the `index` of the items. So in your example there is only one item, you could access it with `Array[0]`. Then you have this object:

```
{"detectedLanguage":
    {"language": "hin", "score": 1.0},
      "translations":[
        {"text":"I am a boy", "to":"en"}
      ]
    }
```

There are two keys in you object, called `detectedLanguage`. Trying to reach `text` you need to access the `translations` key like `Array[0].translations` would give you the following object:

```
[{"text":"I am a boy", "to":"en"}]
```

This is another array with an object as the only item. So we can directly reach to `text` this time by calling `Array[0].translations[0].text` as we refer to the first item of `translations` and the key `text` of the object, so we get:

```
I am a boy
```

To call this like this `Array[0].translations[0].text` we need to store `Array` in a actual array like:

```
let myArray = [
  {"detectedLanguage":
    {"language": "hin", "score": 1.0},
      "translations":[
        {"text":"I am a boy", "to":"en"}
      ]
    }
 ]
```

And then you can just `console.log(myArray[0].translations[0].text)`.